# Convert a string to a list and convert the elements to integers

Tags: python, string, list

So I have a string and I want to convert it to a list

input:

`"123|456|890|60"`

output:

`[123,456,890,60]`

Another example, input:

`"123"`

output:

`[123]`

Here is what I did until now.

```
A=input()
n=len(A)
i=0
z=0
K=""
Y=[0]*n
while(i<n):
  if(A[i]=="|"):
    Y[z]=int(Y[z])
    j=+1
    K=""
  else:
    Y[z]=K+A[i]
  i+=1
print(Y)
```

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. What have you tried, and how did it not work?

Comment: What is stopping you? It is a one liner.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this and update your question accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: With little research you could accomplish this. Just try a bit ?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for editing in your attempt. Splitting a string and converting a string to an integer are very common tasks, and Python has built in tools to achieve them.

`str.split` splits a string into a list by a given delimiter.
`int` can convert a string to an integer. You can use `map` to apply a function to all elements of a list.

```
>>> map(int, "123|456|890|60".split('|'))
[123, 456, 890, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension`

**Code:**

```
[int(a) for a in "123|456|890|60".split("|")]
```

**Output:**

```
[123, 456, 890, 60]
```

**Notes:**

- Split creates a `list of strings` here where the current strings are split at `|`
- We are looping over the list and converting the strings into `int`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar approach, using regular expressions instead:

```
import re

def convert_string(s):
    return map(int, re.findall(r'[0-9]+', s))
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
import re

def convert_string(s):
    return [int(num) for num in re.findall(r'[0-9]+', s)]
```

This is a more general approach and will work for any character (in this case '|') that separates the numbers in the input string.